# CPU Profiling with Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

When viewing Chrome's Task Manager, I see the following:

[image]

That `34.9` is concerning.  So I load up DevTools and take a look at the Javascript Profiler to see this:

[image]

I see that the most amount of time is spent in `toBlob` and `compareFrames` - two array-intensive operations.  I see a lot of other things are related to knockout.  But do all of these things account for the nearly **35%** of my CPU usage?  If not, how can I go about determining what is?  What other tools and techniques are available for diagnosing high CPU usage in a web app through DevTools?

Update: I see that even through Windows Task Manager (Win10) Chrome is taking up ~60% of my `i7`'s CPU.  I profile and see this:

[image]

I've seen several guides (including the [rendering perf guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/) and the [udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/browser-rendering-optimization--ud860) course) but nothing that has given me any insight into how to identify the source of this CPU bottleneck.

Comment: 65% is consumed by the "program", which is compiling, parsing, painting, etc. Start with general  profiling using Performance tab. There are good tutorials in the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm the problem is that the docs are outdated.  For example, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get to this window: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/reduce-the-scope-and-complexity-of-style-calculations.

Comment: [No paint profiler in Chrome DevTools](//stackoverflow.com/a/43039695)

Comment: Check out [Get Started With Analyzing Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) for a more up-to-date tutorial. The general ideas that you find in the [Rendering Perf](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/) docs which you mentioned are still relevant.

Comment: @KayceBasques - thank you.  I just updated my post with what I've tried and what I'm seeing - still a bit stuck here.  I'm working with `getUserMedia` fwiw.